# Decorating a domain object from multiple data sources. Poor design?

Tags: java

I have a primary data source that will return JSON data which I unmarshall to a java POJO.  The secondary data source then uses information from the first Java POJO classes to retrieve additional data from another data source.

My original plan was to have a single POJO that is partially populated by data source one and then completed by data source 2.

But from a purist point this would seem wrong, but I am unsure how you should design the system.

Just for reference, there is no need for this to be done asynchronously.

Comment: Well...  you domain should be independent from where your data is located. If your domain object represents a single concept I see no problem fetching it's data from multiple sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't have a single [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) for everything. I would go with the following:

- Specific [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) class for the data coming from data source 1;
- Specific DTO class for the data coming from data source 2;
- POJO class for your domain model mapped from the 2 specific DTO classes mentioned above.

With this, you clearly separate data sources and use whatever logic you need to merge them into your domain model. With this, you decouple your domain model from the data sources, making it easier to change any of the classes if needed. You could even add or remove a data source easily.

Comment: That does look like a cleaner design.  The only question is whether I pass the DTO objects obtained from DS1 to DS2 as DS2 needs a single field from the DTO objects obtained via DS1 for the query it performs or do I pull out just the single attribute from the DTO1 and pass just what is required so as to remove unnecessary coupling or does it not really matter?

Comment: Pass just what is required to DS2 and not the complete DTO1 object, because as you said that would couple them together. Think about it this way. DS2 is in no way interested in knowing from where the required data comes from, so just pass the data itself and not DTO1 ;)